# How to help the type inference system infer the type of a closure argument?

Tags: rust, type-inference

I have this closure `color`, but the type system cannot infer the type of its `pixel` argument.

```
pub fn solve_part2(input: &[u32]) -> String {
    let color = |pixel| {
        pixel
            .skip_while(|l| **l == 2)
            .next()
            .map(|c| char::from_digit(*c, 10).unwrap())
            .unwrap()
    };

    let pixel = |n| input.iter().skip(n).step_by(25 * 6);
    (0..(25 * 6)).map(|px| color(pixel(px))).collect()
}
```

With the type annotated, it becomes

```
let color = |pixel: std::iter::StepBy<std::iter::Skip<std::slice::Iter<u32>>>| {
    pixel
        .skip_while(|l| **l == 2)
        .next()
        .map(|c| char::from_digit(*c, 10).unwrap())
        .unwrap()
};
```

Are there any tricks to help the type system infer the type of `pixel` without annotating?

Comment: If the `color` closure is only used once, you could move it inline inside the `map` call.

Comment: @Dai That is how I had it initially, but moved it out for clarity. It did work fine inlined.

Comment: Another option is to use a type-alias. You could also make it more succint by importing those types into-scope - Remember that Rust isn't C++ so you don't need to avoid importing namespaces (unlike `using namespace std;` in C++): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29013617/rust-use-vs-c-using-namespace - so there's nothing wrong with having `StepBy<Skip<Itr<u32>>>` in your code.

Comment: Partially relevant discussion about why the type annotations are needed in closures: https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/5g6oa0/can_i_hint_the_types_of_closure_parameters_in/

Comment: Could be a [known issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/12679).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far, I could not come up with something without annotations, but you could reduce the amount of annotation:

You could leave some holes that are to be filled by type inference:

```
pub fn solve_part2(input: &[u32]) -> String {
    let color = |pixel: std::iter::StepBy<_>| {
        pixel
            .skip_while(|l: &&_| **l == 2)
            .next()
            .map(|c| char::from_digit(*c, 10).unwrap())
            .unwrap()
    };
    let pixel = |n| input.iter().skip(n).step_by(25 * 6);
    (0..(25 * 6)).map(|px| color(pixel(px))).collect()
}
```

Alternatively, inline `color`:

```
pub fn solve_part3(input: &[u32]) -> String {
    let pixel = |n| input.iter().skip(n).step_by(25 * 6);
    (0..(25 * 6)).map(|px| pixel(px)
            .skip_while(|l| **l == 2)
            .next()
            .map(|c| char::from_digit(*c, 10).unwrap())
            .unwrap()).collect()
}
```

Alternatively, make `color` a local `fn`:

```
pub fn solve_part3(input: &[u32]) -> String {
    fn color<'a>(pixel: impl Iterator<Item=&'a u32>) -> char {
        pixel
            .skip_while(|l| **l == 2)
            .next()
            .map(|c| char::from_digit(*c, 10).unwrap())
            .unwrap()
    };
    let pixel = |n| input.iter().skip(n).step_by(25 * 6);
    (0..(25 * 6)).map(|px| color(pixel(px))).collect()
}
```